is dbgc a direct replacement for xdc?
I'm looking to replace our ancient xdc (xdebug client) module with something current.
Is the DBGp Client the replacement?
When I look at my old module I see thisxdc module image and I'm not sure how much, if any, of that I need.
When I run our xdc I see this...
xdc gui
read the documentation

The DBGp Client is a command line client, and probably not as useful as XDC (of which I have never heard). I am not aware of a standalone client.

This is the only information I have on it. https://code.google.com/archive/p/xdebugclient/

I remember xdc from the time I wrote the Notepad++ plugin, waay back. Today you can use IDEs that directly support Xdebug or editors that support it via a debug adapter.   I’d suggest you look into what the tools you use offer in regards of Xdebug support.
